# Inline code is not properly formatted after horizontal rule, in documentation examples

Tags: bug, documentation, code-formatting

The following footnote is shown correctly, with an inline code snippet:

[image: Without <hr>, snippet is displayed right]

But if I insert a `<hr>`-rule after the main text, the inline code stops being displayed as such:

[image: <hr> destroys the code snippet layout]

Comment: FWIW, this does not happen if I insert the horizontal rule with `---` instead of `<hr>`. But still...